# How does data-binding in Polymer work?

Tags: polymer

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="new-tag">
    <template>
        <input id="input" value="{{value}}" type="text" />
    </template>
    <script>
        (function () {
            Polymer("new-tag", {
                value: ""
            });
        })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

If I change the `value` property of the DOM object (in JS) I can see that the text field's value changes.
If I change the text field value, the DOM object property `value` also changes.

But both these changes don't affect the `value` attribute.

If the `value` attribute doesn't change, how is the change in model, reflecting in the view?

I was thinking that `value={{value}}` is a way of saying "when the `value` property changes, change the `value` attribute and vice versa". But if `value` attribute is not being the **link** between the view and the model, how are the changes being propagated?

Also, what exactly does `value={{value}}` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see the binding (e.g. `{{value}}`) on the input's `value` attribute change because Polymer needs to establish a two-way binding on that property. If it were to be replaced by the actual value, the value would no longer be data-bound.

There's an entire section in Polymer docs on "How data binding works":
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#how-data-binding-works

> I was thinking that `value={{value}}` is a way of saying "when the `value` property changes, change the `value` attribute and vice versa".

Under the hood, Polymer uses the `Node.bind()`  library to bind the property changes of elements to data. Inputs in particular support 2-way data binding on their `value` and `checked` attributes:

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#binding-to-input-values
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/node_bind.html

Comment: Thank you @ebidel. But my question is, when I change the `value` property of my `new-tag` element, what in the DOM changes to make the input field get this new text I entered? How does Polymer know that it must set `input_field.value = <new_value>` when I change the `value` property of the Polymer element. Similarly, when I change the text in the input field by typing, it changes the `value` property of the input field, but how is this change propagated to the `value` property of the Polymer element?

Comment: As Eric noted, the `Node.prototype.bind()` implementation on `<input>` (aka HTMLInputElement.prototype.bind()`) does all the work you are asking about.

Comment: Link-rot has eaten all three links.

Answer (score 6):

Reflecting property values back to the attribute [is now opt-in](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/lX_gvSOT78Y/UtxDo-M2H6MJ). The docs are in the process of being updated to reflect this. To get this behavior, instead of using the `attributes` attribute on your `polymer-element` tag, use the `publish` property in your call to `Polymer()`, like so:

```
Polymer({
  publish: {
    // won't reflect to an attribute
    bigText: '',
    // will reflect to an attribute
    active: {value: false, reflect: true}
  },
  ...
)};
```

Answer (score 4):

In Polymer 1.0 there is the [two ways data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#two-way-native) for native elements or in general non-Polymer elements. You need to specify the event `::input` as in the following instruction:

```
 <input id="input" value="{{modelvalue::input}}" type="text" />
```

Anytime the user types something in the text box, the `modelvalue` property is updated. Hence, element attribute value and property value are in sync.

**Code snippet**

The following is a complete working and running example:

```html
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module is="new-wc">
    <template>
       
      <input id="input" value="{{modelvalue::input}}" type="text" />
      
      <p>
        Default value is <span>{{modelvalue}}</span>  
      </p>
      
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
         is: "new-wc",

         properties: {
            modelvalue: { type: String, value: "0" }
         }
      });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<p><b>Code snippet description: </b>this polymer code snippet demonstrates how to use the two ways binding for native or non-polymer elements. Just type something within the text box and you will see the typed text updated below.</p>
  
<new-wc></new-wc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Non polymer elements (basic html tags) needs to tell polymer when will they  update the value by event names. So value={{value::eventname}}
For text inputs ->

```
value={{value::input}}
```